# Securely (https) convert Javascript reports from HTML to PDF

Tags: java, html, pdf, export-to-pdf

In my JAVA web application I have a HTML report page which is created using a large number of Javascript charts (using highcharts) as well as text based data. It is confidential data on a secure page which requires the user to log in. I need to allow users to click on a link which will save the report as a PDF document.

I need a cost effective solution which doesn't require data to be passed to any third party servers. I want to avoid the need to template PDFs, I would rather that it takes the HTML view and creates a PDF from that.

What products/technical solutions are available to me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I did not fully check this, but Google told me this: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2006/jw-0410-html.html
Looks pretty much like what you need...

Comment: You could just have people install a PDF "printer" driver (cups-pdf on Linux, http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/ on Windows, MacOSX should be able to do this out of the box). Chrome can also directly save any web page as PDF from its print dialog on any platform. Neither of these approaches required any changes to the actual app nor passing any data to a third party.

Comment: Many of our users have locked down systems and are forced to use Internet Explorer 8 therefore it needs to be an 'in application' solution. Otherwise, yes, it would save so much time not having to worry about this.

Comment: Presumably 'in application' doesn't mean 'client side only'? If not, then consider `wkhtmltopdf` or maybe even PrinceXML, though the latter isn't cheap.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean client side only. I was guessing that it would be some serverside solution.